# MS Word, OpenXML, PageSetup, Orientation and 4_directional Margins

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, openxml

**I made this document with OpenXML.** . I'm learning OpenXML. Oh.. it is so difficult.

```
MainDocumentPart m = wd.AddMainDocumentPart();
m.Document = new Document();
Body b1 = new Body();
int myCount = 5;
for (int z = 1; z <= myCount; z++)
{
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    Run r1 = new Run();
    Text t1 = new Text(
        "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog  " + z );
    r1.Append(t1);                      
    p1.Append(r1);
    b1.Append(p1);
}
m.Document.Append(b1);
```

[image]

I'd like to change its orientation from portrait -> landscape and to set its margin smaller.

Before process;

[image]

After process;
[image]

I can achieve this goal with VBA codes like this;

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape  
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
End With
```

But, when I go to OpenXML area, it is quite different.

Can I have some tips ?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`SectionProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sectionproperties(v=office.15).aspx), [`PageSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.pagesize(v=office.15).aspx) and [`PageMargin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.pagemargin(v=office.15).aspx) classes like so:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wd = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart m = wd.AddMainDocumentPart();
    m.Document = new Document();
    Body b1 = new Body();

    //new code to support orientation and margins
    SectionProperties sectProp = new SectionProperties();
    PageSize pageSize = new PageSize() { Width = 16838U, Height = 11906U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape };
    PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin() { Top = 720, Right = 720U, Bottom = 720, Left = 720U };

    sectProp.Append(pageSize);
    sectProp.Append(pageMargin);
    b1.Append(sectProp);
    //end new code

    int myCount = 5;
    for (int z = 1; z <= myCount; z++)
    {
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        Run r1 = new Run();
        Text t1 = new Text(
            "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog  " + z);
        r1.Append(t1);
        p1.Append(r1);
        b1.Append(p1);
    }
    m.Document.Append(b1);
}
```

Note that the page margin values are defined in twentieths of a point. 1.27cm is roughly 36 points which is 720 twentieths of a point.

Comment: Works.. Yeah..nice, really nice. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Jason I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Ahh.. Can I have one more tip please ?

Comment: Ahh. something like "  .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly   or   .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 10""... I am typing it though... sorry...

Comment: Sorry @Jason, I'm confused. I'm happy to try to help but I'm not sure what you're asking here?

Comment: Ok... I will google it. and If I fail to find a good answer. I'll post another one. THANKS.................

Comment: Your answer is good. I have already google some though.. That is too difficult to me.