# Setting word margin with vb.net(cant figure out)

Tags: vb.net, openxml-sdk, margins

I refer to [MS Word, OpenXML, PageSetup, Orientation and 4_directional Margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003078/ms-word-openxml-pagesetup-orientation-and-4-directional-margins) and convert it into vb.net.I faced exception and cannot figure it out.Exception:Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent in this line

```
Dim m As MainDocumentPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart()
```

Below is my code:

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
Public Class Form1
Const strMyDoc As String = "C:\Users\eric\Desktop\vb testing purpose\test.docx"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'OpenDocument
    Dim doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(strMyDoc, True)
    Dim m As MainDocumentPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart()
    m.Document = New Document()
    Dim b1 As Body = New Body()


    'code to support orientation And margins
    Dim sectProp As SectionProperties = New SectionProperties()
    Dim PageSize As PageSize = New PageSize() With {.Width = 16838, .Height = 11906, .Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape}
    Dim PageMargin As PageMargin = New PageMargin() With {.Top = 720, .Right = 720, .Bottom = 720, .Left = 720}

    sectProp.Append(PageSize)
    sectProp.Append(PageMargin)
    b1.Append(sectProp)

    doc.Close()
    Process.Start(strMyDoc)
End Sub

End Class
```

Besides,is there any other error/exception/suggestion to do margin?Welcome to point out too.

Comment: Please give exact details HOW it "doesn't function". What result are you expecting and how does it differ from what you're getting? Note that you shouldn't be setting any Rsid stuff in your Open XML code - this is change tracking that Word generates automatically when a document is edited in the UI and certain (default) settings are active.

Comment: Hi Cindy Meister,actually what i expecting is i want to using OpenXML to change the margin of word,but the code i write are not function and also no any error in there so...i cannot debug it where wrong,and what is the Rsid?

Comment: thank you,i think i got what you means

Comment: Is it working, now?

Comment: Yes,its work now